# Javascript: Why Are My Tab Contents Disappearing When I Add Other Href Links To Other Sections Of The Webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, tabs

Okay to start off, I already have my tabs in working order (as demonstrated by this fiddle:  [tab fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1qr0qmzk/4/)

**BUT** when I try to add links Link anywhere else on the webpage, my tabs break and won't display the tab contents and the tabs themselves become unclickable.  Why is that?

I'm stumped on a workaround for this.

Oh, and just a note, I did my tab script in simple Javascript because it is **absolutely mandatory** for my to do it in **simple Javascript**.  I'm not allowed to use JQuery or any other method other than simple Javascript to do the tabs.

Here's my code for the tab script:

```js
//Tab initialization
var listenReady = setInterval(function() {
  if (document.readyState == "complete") {
    clearInterval(listenReady);
    makeTabs(".tabs");
  };
}, 10);

function makeTabs(selector) {

  tab_lists_anchors = document.querySelectorAll(selector + " li a");
  divs = document.querySelector(selector).querySelectorAll("div");

  for (var i = 0; i < tab_lists_anchors.length; i++) {
    console.log(tab_lists_anchors[i].classList)
    if (tab_lists_anchors[i].classList.contains('active')) {
      divs[i].style.display = "block";
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < tab_lists_anchors.length; i++) {

    document.querySelectorAll(".tabs li a")[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {

      for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        divs[i].style.display = "none";
      }

      for (i = 0; i < tab_lists_anchors.length; i++) {
        console.log(tab_lists_anchors[i].classList)
        tab_lists_anchors[i].classList.remove("active");
      }

      clicked_tab = e.target || e.srcElement;
      clicked_tab.classList.add('active');
      div_to_show = clicked_tab.getAttribute('href');
      document.querySelector(div_to_show).style.display = "block";

    });
  }
}
```

```css
.tabs {
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: both;
}
.tabs ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  bottom: -1px;
  position: relative;
}
.tabs li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0;
}
.tabs a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: #EEE;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #DDD;
  border-left: 1px solid #DDD;
  font: 13px/18px verdana, arial, sans-serif;
}
.tabs a.active {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
.tabs div {
  clear: both;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 13px;
  background-color: purple;
  display: none;
  min-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <ul>
    <!-- Tab Headings -->
    <li><a href="#tab1" class="active">Tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab4">Tab4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab Contents -->
  <div id="tab1">
    <h1>Tab 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum. Contents of tab 1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ultrices ante vel elementum tristique. In suscipit nisi et purus cursus, eget tincidunt nunc mattis. Duis commodo mollis interdum. Vestibulum ante
      ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In efficitur massa et ex gravida imperdiet. Phasellus finibus arcu ut erat dignissim efficitur. Curabitur quam ipsum, volutpat et elit et, sollicitudin malesuada mi. Praesent
      eget dui dui.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="tab2">
    <h1>Tab 2</h1>
    <p>Contents of tab 2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ultrices ante vel elementum tristique. In suscipit nisi et purus cursus, eget tincidunt nunc mattis. Duis commodo mollis interdum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis
      in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In efficitur massa et ex gravida imperdiet. Phasellus finibus arcu ut erat dignissim efficitur. Curabitur quam ipsum, volutpat et elit et, sollicitudin malesuada mi. Praesent eget dui dui.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="tab3">
    <h1>Tab 3</h1>
    <p>Contents of tab . Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ultrices ante vel elementum tristique. In suscipit nisi et purus cursus, eget tincidunt nunc mattis. Duis commodo mollis interdum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis
      in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In efficitur massa et ex gravida imperdiet. Phasellus finibus arcu ut erat dignissim efficitur. Curabitur quam ipsum, volutpat et elit et, sollicitudin malesuada mi. Praesent eget dui dui.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="tab4">
    <h1>Tab 4</h1>
    <p>Contents of tab 4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ultrices ante vel elementum tristique. In suscipit nisi et purus cursus, eget tincidunt nunc mattis. Duis commodo mollis interdum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis
      in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In efficitur massa et ex gravida imperdiet. Phasellus finibus arcu ut erat dignissim efficitur. Curabitur quam ipsum, volutpat et elit et, sollicitudin malesuada mi. Praesent eget dui dui.</p>
  </div>
</div>

 <div>
      <a href="https://www.google.com/">Google Link Example</a>
 </div>
```

EDITED:  put in an href link for Google homepage as an example.  Links like these are breaking my tab code and causes it to not work properly.

Comment: You need to post the code that's not working, not the working code. How can we tell what you're doing wrong when you add the links?

Comment: No, as I've stated I have a problem when I post <a href> links anywhere on the webpage.  I've tried placing it everywhere in every section whether in the header, footer, main section, etc.  Everytime I put an <a href> anywhere else on the page, my whole tab code breaks.  And I can't figure out why it's just when I place <a href> links that does this.  Everything else is fine.

Comment: If you post a fiddle of the non-working code, I can tell you specifically what is going on, but I would start with looking at the fact that your tabs div is wrapped around the whole content, meaning styles/scripts get applied to many elements (.tabs a for example). The tabs still work with a link though, see this https://jsfiddle.net/1qr0qmzk/5/.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem of tabs breaking when I add anchors to the contents.

Comment: One problem I noticed is that you have CSS for `.tabs a` that should be `.tabs li a`, so the links in the contents get wrong styling. You also have lots of variables that aren't declared local with `var`.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem either

Comment: I suspect you have some other code on your actual page that's somehow interfering with the combination of tabs and anchors. Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: I just checked on console and no errors are showing up.  However though, I caught this one by eye:  in my script there's  a code .getElementsByTagName(" li a").  Could this be interfering and selecting all the <a href> links all over the webpage?  EDIT:  there's also a code .getAttribute('href').

Comment: @fanvaorite Okay, give me 5 mins and I'll put my whole file on a fiddle.

Comment: Here's the FULL file on a fiddle:  [link](https://jsfiddle.net/gLss0g0g/)

Comment: @5120bee Sorry, still can't repro the problem.  The full code you put in your fiddle works fine for me.  What browser are you using?  (may actually be an issue with `http://my.gblearn.com/js/loadscript.js`.  I can't download this due to cross site scripting contraints.  Maybe the problem is in there)

Comment: @Tibrogargan That particular code is just something that my institution implements to load javascripts.  It hasn't caused any problem before, and I don't think that's the source.  Thanks for your help though.  I'm suspecting that it's something to do with the .getElementsByTagName or .getAttribute that selects all the "a" and "href" tags on the entire webpage...

Comment: @Tibrogargan P.S.-- were you able to click on the Tab links and switch between tabs?  Did it display the correct tab content for your browser?  I'm using Chrome and mine doesn't... even on the fiddle.

Comment: @5120bee Odd.  The fiddle doesn't work for me either, but it works when I copied all the fiddle panes into a new html file.